# Como clicar em um link de um frame utilizando Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Estou estudando um livro Automatize Tarefas Massantes com Python. Estou na página 317 que fala sobre Selenium WebDriver sobre os métodos de encontrar elementos nas páginas.

Tabela 11.3 – Os métodos de WebDriver do Selenium para encontrar elementos.
Após fazer este pequeno exemplo abaixo eu parei/empanquei na hora de clicar no link Wireles do lado esquerdo da página. Pois notei que o link faz parte de um frame e o mesmo "não se encontra" na página atual. *Roteador Wireless N 300Mbps WR840N modelo TL-WR840N*.

```
#Importando selenium
from selenium import webdriver
#Importando as teclas especiais {ENTER}{TAB}{DOWN}...
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
#Escolhendo o browser padrao
browser=webdriver.Chrome()
#abrindo o endereco do roteador
browser.get('http://192.168.100.1')
#maximizando a janela atual
browser.maximize_window()
#Digitando o usuario
browser.find_element_by_id('userName').send_keys('admin')
#Digitando a senha
browser.find_element_by_id('pcPassword').send_keys('admin')
#Clicando no botao Login
browser.find_element_by_id('loginBtn').click()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Importante um [mcve] de forma a ninguém precisar de dispositivo similar para avaliar a solução.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode usar o [`switch_to_frame`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html) do [driver](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html) para mudar o contexto para a *frame*:

```
// usando o nome da frame
driver.switch_to_frame(["nome da frame"])

// usando um localizador (vulgo find_element_by)
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_?)
```

Após ter mudado para a *frame* com sucesso, pode procurar os elementos que deseja:

```
driver.switch_to_frame("frame").find_element_by_id("menu_wl").click();
```